# "Join us!" vs "Join in us!"

Tags: prepositions, expressions, imperative-sentences

I ran today into a weird piece of English.

We were a few colleagues chit-chatting on the hallway at work. Another colleague passed by, and we invited him to chat with us.

I expected the invitation to be:

> Join us!

However, one of those colleagues, taking English classes as a foreigner, told us, as explained by his teacher (also not native English speaker), that the following is also fine, with the same meaning:

> Join **in** us!

And also that the following is wrong:

> Join **to** us!

I never ever encountered the second form, and I think that only "Join us!" is correct.

Bottom line: is "Join in us!" also correct / acceptable?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

'*Join in us*' is incorrect. 'To **join in**' can be used in the context of involving in an activity:

> Join in our discussion. Join us. We are going to play football, you
>   can join in/us.

More '**join in**' examples: https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/join-in-sth

Comment: I completely forgot about "Join in!" Tanks.

Answer (score 1):

Here is what [Google Books NGram Viewer](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=join%20*%20us%2C%20join%20us&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t2%3B%2Cjoin%20%2A%20us%3B%2Cc0%3B%2Cs0%3B%3Bjoin%20with%20us%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Bjoin%20against%20us%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Bjoin%20to%20us%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Bjoin%20before%20us%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Bjoin%20the%20us%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cjoin%20us%3B%2Cc0#t2%3B%2Cjoin%20*%20us%3B%2Cc0%3B%2Cs0%3B%3Bjoin%20with%20us%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Bjoin%20against%20us%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Bjoin%20to%20us%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Bjoin%20before%20us%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Bjoin%20the%20us%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cjoin%20us%3B%2Cc0) shows, indicating at least the written word:

[image: join (preposition) us]

Although this is a case sensitive search, it's possible that some of these hits, in particular *join **the** us*, could represent *join [preposition] US* (or *United States*).

In any case, there is a *much* greater frequency of simply *join us* than there is of any use of a preposition. Although you can't tell from the picture itself, only *join **with** us* is represented by the higher blue line. All of the other instances exist at the very bottom of the chart, sharing an almost nonexistent usage.

Of particular note is that *join **in** us* doesn't exist at all.

Based on this, and mirroring my own sense of idiomatic usage, I would say that you should use either just *join us* or, in a distance second case, *join **with** us*.

Comment: What about "Join in!" ? (from another answer). I think it would be idiomatic too. Or?

Comment: @virolino Yes, but you didn't ask about that in your question . . . You could also use *join our discussion*.